# Using database tables with bigint columns in ArcMap query layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, postgresql, query-layer

I am very new to GIS and am using the ArcMap 10 program.

Currently, I am trying to set up a query layer from a remote database. I am able to connect to the database, but I am having trouble making the query because the table I want to use has a "bigint" column. From what I have read, ArcMap does not support this data type directly, though some sources suggest that there is a workaround by manually writing a query in the "name" and "Query" fields instead of using the "List of tables" and "columns" selection menus. I've tried this "workaround", and have not succeeded.

Is there any way that I can use my database in a query layer without modifying the database at all? Or can I connect the database to ArcMap in another way?

I am using a PostgreSQL DBMS.

Comment: This may or may not be a reference that you have read to say "ArcMap does not support this data type directly" (http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/48490-BigInt-PostGIS-quot-Invalid-Column-Data-Type-quot-in-Desktop) but thought I would post in case it helps others assist you

Answer (score 1):

In the query you used to define the Query Layer, you could cast this bigint column to another type that is supported by ArcGIS.

```
SELECT CAST(yourbigintcolumn as float)
```